# Sending decoded pdf file returns blank pdf

Tags: python, java, pdf, decode, apigee

The task here was to decode a pdf file and send it as a form-data.

The backend receives the decoded pdf file and everything on apigee end seemed to work fine.

When we go to check the received pdf file, it's blank, but it's not empty as the size is not 0.

I used a python policy to decode and a java callout to create the form-data.

here is the python code used in the policy :

```
import base64


pdfB64 = flow.getVariable("File")

pdfFile = base64.standard_b64decode(pdfB64)
flow.setVariable("pdfFileDecoded",pdfFile)
```

and here is the java policy :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<JavaCallout name="Java-CreateMultipartForm">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="contentVar">pdfFileDecoded</Property>
        <Property name="contentType">application/pdf</Property>
        <Property name="want-base64-decode">false</Property>
        <Property name="part-name">{Name}</Property>
        <Property name="fileName">{fileName}</Property>
    </Properties>
    <ClassName>com.google.apigee.callouts.MultipartFormCreator</ClassName>
    <ResourceURL>java://apigee-multipart-form-20210401.jar</ResourceURL>
</JavaCallout>
```

[The code used in the Java policy comes from this repo](https://github.com/DinoChiesa/Apigee-Java-Simple-MultipartForm)

Any idea why it returns a blank pdf instead of a readable file ? I checked the file using an online decoder and it's not corrupt.

[image: Here's an image of the flow]

Comment: I tried going into python, decoding and writing to a file and the pdf file shows up as it's supposed to. So I don't understand why on the backend it shows as a blank file.

Comment: I looked into what you said, but the thing is, there's no text before the %PDF, it's only headers then boundary. I'm not sure why I keep getting a blanc pdf on the backend. Do you think I should proceed in a different way as oppose to what I'm doing now ?

Comment: I used python to see how it will render the decoding, and even in python when I print out the variable containing the decoded pdf it starts with the `%`, More so I generate a file using the same variable on python and it's not corrupt, it renders correctly. However when it is sent through apigee it's blanc. I don't think the problem lies in the body or the decoding. I'm not sure tho how to send it specifically as a binary stream, do you have an idea how to do that ? as I'm new to apigee